# OSGi bundle error : Access restriction for org.slf4j

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi-bundle

I have 2 OSGi plugins in eclipse. MENIFEST.MF files of both these plugins have imported org.slf4j package. But I am getting below error in one of the above two plugins.

```
Access restriction: The type Logger is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\workspaces\PolicyServer_9.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins\slf4j.api_1.6.0.jar
```

I explored and found https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openhab/CbQ8QDCMsqA which I do not think is helpful as it suggests to create a new project altogether.
There is eclipse setting which turns this Error to Warning but I want to fix the Error instead of converting it in warnings. Does anyone have any idea about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the current latest version available here [slf4j download page](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html). I'm using version 1.7.12 successfully inside Eclipse and the latest version 1.7.21 at the moment is also working fine.